# Trying to seal light from LEDs on PCB

Tags: led, pcb, pcb-design, altium, light

I have a PCB I'm currently working on in Altium where the only thing on the bottom are some LEDs that I'd like to mount through a cutout on a sheet of plastic, with all of the other components on the top. The PCB will be directly attached to the plastic sheet via some bolts, but I am concerned that any imperfections in the PCB could lead to light escaping out of any gap between the PCB and the plastic, and because I'm planning to use this in a darkroom I can't afford to have any light leak out in this fashion.

I'm looking into the idea of using some kind of O-ring-like seals around the LEDs and around the bolts, to ensure the light can't escape in unintended directions, but I'm not sure how I would be able to attach these to the PCB, as I don't think that leaving the rings loose around the LEDs is going to work very well when I try and make multiple of these devices.

If anyone has any similar experience, I'd really love to hear how this kind of problem has been solved in the past. I'm considering some kind of cutout on the PCB to help keep the rings in place, or perhaps some kind of sealant to bond the rings to the PCB, but I don't know how practical either idea is (I've never seen cut-outs in PCBs like I'd need to seat the rings, and I'm afraid using a sealant on the rings could end up causing them to not work correctly) or if there are other solutions that are just better.

Thanks.

Comment: It should be easy to glue black felt washers to the plastic, and they are commercially available.

Comment: I have never heard of felt washers, I'll be sure to check them out!

Comment: it is difficult to visualize what you are trying to do .... what are you building?

Comment: I would worry more about the edges on the cutout in the plastic transmitting light to unwanted places. If it is completely opaque and bonded to the PCB not much will likely get out. This kind of thing you might want to experiment with in real life rather than guessing.

Comment: You are dealing with a problem that you didn't have before lighting up those LED's. If the board is meant to be used in absolute darkness, why are there LED's in the board? If the LED's are for indication or debugging, they could be in a removable breakout board. Or, there could be a way of disabling the LED's. It's somewhat strange that you need complete darkness, but your own circuit is lighting up some LED's.

Comment: To clarify, I will be bolting the PCB to the plastic, so it is removable, not bonding it.

Comment: Also to clarify, the LEDs ARE the application. I'm trying to create a light source of a very specific character, and I don't want any light leaking out the back of the unit and interfering with my calculations regarding a series of light sensors I'll be using.